# SQL: How To Append Semi-Colon To Column Value.

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column in my database named details_location which references the second part of a url ex. "manager\reports\user\description\UsersRights.htm" I'd like to append a semi-colon to each row value, so that the above appears as "manager\reports\user\description\UsersRights.htm;"

I've tried using something like

```
update reportdescriptions
set details_location = details_location+';'
```

To no avail, I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing. Thanks!

Comment: You are using SQL Server syntax in mysql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try CONCAT function

```
update reportdescriptions set details_location = concat(details_location,';')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
update reportdescriptions
set details_location = CONCAT(details_location, ';');
```

For more info on `CONCAT`, check [THIS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat).

Comment: @rich.okelly copy paste problem ^^

Answer (score 0):

You want `concat(field_name,"string to add")`

Answer (score 0):

What error you get?
If you have a column of type text you may need to cast it to varchar() first 
or CONCAT() like

```
UPDATE reportdescriptions
SET details_location = CONCAT(details_location , ';');
```